# drupal theme not show in appearance

Tags: theming

My new drupal theme zeropiont isnt showing up in drupal 7.
I placed zeropint drupal theme in the /sites/all/themes or sites/default/themes directories.
It is not showing into appearance.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure your theme contains a [`zeropint.info`](https://drupal.org/node/171205) file. This makes Drupal see it at admin/appearance
- [Clear the Drupal cache](https://drupal.org/node/42055)

Now your theme should be listed

Comment: It is worth noting that `sites/default/themes` isn't a part of Drupal core. Only `sites/default/default.settings.php` file is. You could find it excluded in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: You're right I was thinking about sites/themes (which is part of core). Sorry for the wrong info, I'll update my answer.